# Set default value when radio button click to listbox

Tags: javascript

i have created a three radio button and on click i display the list box depending on click so now they are constant ,country,state,city..so now if i click a constant and country some value will display then i have to select  constant and state so now the country as to be set default value that is empty value ...like wise if i select city then state and country will be set as default value (i.e) empty value

```
<table>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="B" id="countrys" value="country"
                onclick="fun(this.value)"></td>
            <td>Country</td>


            <td><input type="radio" name="B" id="states" value="state"
                onclick="fun(this.value)"></td>
            <td>State</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="B" id="citys" value="city"
                onclick="fun(this.value)"></td>
            <td>City</td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

kinldy refer this link 
[Jsfiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/senthil4040/4BJ9V/2/)

Comment: Dont use the **font** element - its deprecated/dead. Ideally you should have no inline style in your document

Comment: tables and font tags reminds me of 1997... good times (not for the web but good times)

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi put this code in body onload function.



var ss=document.getElementById("citys").value;

document.getElementById("citys").checked=true;

ss.onclick=fun(ss);
```

your jsfiiled fu function look like this

```
function fu()
     {

         document.getElementById("country").style.display='none';
         document.getElementById("state").style.display='none';
         document.getElementById("city").style.display='none';
         var ss=document.getElementById("citys").value;
        document.getElementById("citys").checked=true;
        ss.onclick=fun(ss);
     }
```

Comment: yaa i will check your code in Jsfiidle and then after i will give this code for you. just paste code end in your fu function.

Comment: just copy this code in your fu function end and test with jsfiidle.
its working fine i will check.

Comment: u checked a radio-button as default..but my thing is..depend on clickable of radio-button other list box value have to be set default value as empty value ?????